# How to exclude WTI like posts from the Questions page in Q/A plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with the excluding category/posts/pages/ from in the Wti like posts plugin, i have added one page its id is 151, i have given this id in the excluding list in the same plugin, but the like buttons are appearing. suppose i have a url like domainname/questions/php, here questions is the page its id=151, and category is php, this id is added to the excluding category,  will that affect my blogs with the same category? How can i exclude WTI Like post from the domainname/questions/ pages and corresponding categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into you custom plugin folder, and find the css file
(in my example: plugins/dw-question-answer/inc/templates/default/assets/css)

- and then add:

  .watch-action {
  display: none;
  }

To that css file, to disable it showing on that plugin / custom category (posts)

Check out, how its working here with this fix i came up with:
[Inventograde.com](http://inventograde.com)